# Image in UITextField only showing in first text box, not second

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

need to add a downward facing arrow to a text box. decided to use the rightViewMode to display it. it works for the first textfield i use, but does not show up in the second. it happens in 3 different views where i need to do this.

code:

```
//added to post
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 30)];

UIView *rightPaddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 20)];
UIImageView *unitArrowImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"prev-arrow.png"]];
unitArrowImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
[unitArrowImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
[rightPaddingView addSubview:unitArrowImage];

//other code

UITextField *seedRateUnitTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:myRect];
seedRateUnitTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:textFieldFont size:textFieldFontSize];
seedRateUnitTextField.placeholder = @"Unit";
seedRateUnitTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
seedRateUnitTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
seedRateUnitTextField.textColor = [UIColor textFieldTextColor];
seedRateUnitTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
seedRateUnitTextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor textfieldBorderColor]CGColor];
seedRateUnitTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
seedRateUnitTextField.leftView = paddingView;
seedRateUnitTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
seedRateUnitTextField.rightView = rightPaddingView;
seedRateUnitTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
seedRateUnitTextField.delegate = self;
seedRateUnitTextField.tag = 0;
[myScrollView addSubview:seedRateUnitTextField];
[self.dataSetDictionary setValue:seedRateUnitTextField forKey:@"seedRateUnitData"];

myRect = CGRectMake(200, ((4 * 40) + 140), 170, 30);

UITextField *plantingDepthTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:myRect];
plantingDepthTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:textFieldFont size:textFieldFontSize];
plantingDepthTextField.placeholder = @"Enter Planting Depth";
plantingDepthTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
plantingDepthTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
plantingDepthTextField.textColor = [UIColor textFieldTextColor];
plantingDepthTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
plantingDepthTextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor textfieldBorderColor]CGColor];
plantingDepthTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
plantingDepthTextField.leftView = paddingView;
plantingDepthTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
plantingDepthTextField.delegate = self;
plantingDepthTextField.tag = 0;
[myScrollView addSubview:plantingDepthTextField];
[self.dataSetDictionary setValue:plantingDepthTextField forKey:@"plantingDepthData"];

myRect = CGRectMake(375, ((4 * 40) + 140), 85, 30);

UITextField *plantingDepthUnitTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:myRect];
plantingDepthUnitTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:textFieldFont size:textFieldFontSize];
plantingDepthUnitTextField.placeholder = @"Unit";
plantingDepthUnitTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
plantingDepthUnitTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
plantingDepthUnitTextField.textColor = [UIColor textFieldTextColor];
plantingDepthUnitTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
plantingDepthUnitTextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor textfieldBorderColor]CGColor];
plantingDepthUnitTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
plantingDepthUnitTextField.leftView = paddingView;
plantingDepthUnitTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
plantingDepthUnitTextField.rightView = rightPaddingView;
plantingDepthUnitTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
plantingDepthUnitTextField.delegate = self;
plantingDepthUnitTextField.tag = 0;
[myScrollView addSubview:plantingDepthUnitTextField];
[self.dataSetDictionary setValue:plantingDepthUnitTextField forKey:@"plantingDepthUnitData"];
```

result:

[image: result]

this method works great to add padding to the left side. its almost like the rightPaddingView gets used up in the first text box.... /boggle

Comment: sorry, wanted to show all the code to see that nothing changes between the 2 text fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cant add the same UIImageView to two textfields, a UIView can only be in one view at a time, so you should make various instances of your imageview, as many as you want textfields and assign it like that..

Comment: but i use "UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 30)];" in each textfield just fine, is it just the UIImageView thats messing it up? or does it have to do with when i addSubView?

Comment: @Log139 not sure i understand your question, but if you are making a new UIView for each and adding the same UIImageView, then yes that is a problem, you should make one UIImageView for each UIView

Comment: @Log139 The main point is, you will need to add a separate image view for each of your text Fields in order to make your code work.

Comment: sorry, was confused why i could use "UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 30)];" in multiple textfields for left side padding but not one with a UIImage. not sure what the logic for that being is.

Comment: @Log139 a UIImageView is a UIView, you cant create just one and add to all your UIViews, you have to create as many as you have UIViews, in fact you can use a UIImageView without a UIView just the same...